# Need a little help proving that $log(x)\le x-1\quad \forall x\in (0,\infty)$

Tags: calculus

$$log(x):=\int_1^x \frac{1}{t}dt$$
I've already proved that $log(x)\le x-1\;\ \forall x\ge 1\; $, but got stuck with the part where $x\in (0,1)$:

So, since $x\in (0,1)$, then $\frac{1}{x}>1$ and applying what I've already proved I got:
$$log\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)\le \frac{1}{x}-1=\frac{1-x}{x}\\
\text{where}\;\ log\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)=-log(x)\\
\Rightarrow-log(x)\le \frac{1-x}{x}\\
\Rightarrow log(x)\ge \frac{x-1}{x}$$
And then got stuck. I think that the fact of $x\in (0,1)$ could help when multiplying the last inequiality by $x$, but I can't see how. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x \in (0,1)$,

$$\ln x  = \int_1^x \frac{dt}{t} = -\int_x^1 \frac{dt}{t} \color{red}{<} -\int_x^1 1 \ dt = -(1-x) = x - 1$$

The inequality $\color{red}{<}$ follows as for $t \in (x,1)$, $1/t > 1$ and thus $\int_x^1 dt/t > \int_x^1 \ dt$, implying $-\int_x^1 dt/t \color{red}{<} -\int_x^1 \ dt$.

Answer (score 2):

This is usually solved by calculus. You want to show that the minimum of the function
$$f(x) = x - 1 - \log(x)$$
on $(0,\infty)$ is 0. From calculus, we know extreme value occurs at the roots of $f'(x) = 0$. In this case, solving $0 = 1 - \frac{1}{x}$ gives us $x = 1$. [Note that $\log(x)' = \frac{1}{|x|}$ but we are in $(0,\infty)$ so we can take $\log(x)' = \frac{1}{x}$.] So the minimum of $f(x)$ is $f(1) = 1 - 1 - \log(1) = 0$. This proves the inequality.

Answer (score 1):

A concave function stays below any of its tangent lines, and $\ln x$  is concave. Its tangent line at $(1,0)$ is $y=x-1.$ We're done.